# The type or namespace name 'WindowsSecureMimeContext' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to use MimeKit to send digitally signed emails.  The certificate I am using to sign the emails is stored in the LocalMachine certificate store, so I want to use the `WindowsSecureMimeContext`.  However I am getting a type or namespace could not be found error when trying to use it.  I have included `MimeKit` and `MimeKit.Cryptography`, but the error still persists.  I am trying to use it in a class library project targeting .NET Core 2.2 if that makes a difference.

Here is my code, any idea why I'm getting the error?

```
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Cryptography;
using BO;

namespace BLL
{
    public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {    
        public void Send(Email email)
        {
            CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.Subject = email.Subject;
            using (var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine)) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the updated code that I was able to get working.

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Cryptography;
using OGC.CIS.ADR.BO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace OGC.CIS.ADR.BLL
{
    public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public EmailService(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public void Send(Email email)
        {
            CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(MySecureMimeContext));
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            var sender = new MailboxAddress(_config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:SubjectCN"));
            message.From.Add(sender);
            message.Subject = email.Subject;
            var body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = email.Body
            };
            using (var ctx = new MySecureMimeContext()) {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, _config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:SubjectCN"), true);
                //var cert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certs[0]);
                ctx.Import(certs[0]);
                message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, sender, DigestAlgorithm.Sha256, body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the updated Import method I created to store the private key.

```
public void Import (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    if (certificate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(certificate));
    var bcCert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);
    var fingerprint = bcCert.GetFingerprint();
    if (fingerprints.Add(fingerprint))
        certificates.Add(bcCert);

    if (!keys.ContainsKey(fingerprint))
        keys.Add(fingerprint, Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certificate.PrivateKey).Private);    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowsSecureMimeContext does not exist in the .NETStandard 2.0 version of the library because the System.Security API's needed for that class don't exist.

You'll need to write a custom SecureMimeContext class.You'll most likely want to subclass either DefaultSecureMimeContext or TemporarySecureMimeContext if you just want something super simple.

Comment: I managed to get it working using TemporarySecureMimeContext, but was having an issue with losing the private key on import.  I ended up having to modify the context to add in a new Import method that took in a X509Certificate2 from the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace and add the private key from that to the keys dictionary.  Not sure if this is the correct or right way to do it, but it works.  Updated my original post with the new code and am open to suggestions.